# What is the meaning of そう君と二人 in the sentence below?

Tags: translation, meaning, nuances

My question is what **そう君と二人** means in this sentence:

> **そう君と二人**で冷たい月に手を伸ばして
> （Sō kimi to futari de tsumetai tsuki ni te wo nobashite)

I know that *tsumetai tsuki ni te wo nobashite* means something among the lines of *"reach out your hand toward the cold moon"*, but I just can't seem to figure out what to do with **そう君と二人**. As far as I know, it means *"So you and 2 people(...)"*, though I don't really know how I should convey it into the full sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「そう」, in this context, means "yes", not "so".  (For fairness, one could argue that "yes" and "so" are related as they are both used for affirmation.)  It is the introspective kind of "yes" that one uses to affirm and/or remember an event involving oneself.

This 「そう」 is quite often used in song lyrics, light poetry, romantic letters, etc.

「君{きみ}と二人{ふたり}」 means "you and I" or "the two of us".  It does ***not*** mean "you and 2 people" as you stated.

So, the whole line means:

***"Yes, the two of us reach(ed) out our hands toward the cold moon."***

(It is impossible to decide on the tense because 「伸{の}ばして」 is not an natural sentence ending.  More context needed to decide on the tense here.)

Comment: Ooow, okay... Now I understand. So 「君」 can sometimes also be plural, meaning 'us' or 'we'. And thanks for the detailed explanation on the word 「そう」, I never thought it could just plainly mean 'yes'. You were very helpful, l'électeur. Though, I hope you don't mind helping me one more time with this piece of text: 「仕組まれてる」。

「仕組ま」or「仕組む」means to plan (something), but what does 「れてる」 mean. Is it another form of the verb Shikumu?

Comment: About the tense, this sentence is preceded by 「もう逃げない この場所で」(Not being able to escape from this place anymore), so I'm guessing it's the present.

Comment: No, 「君」 does not me "us". 「君と二人」 means "us" (It's more along the lines of "together with you").

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thanks for the elaboration, Jimmy. Is there a chance you know what 「仕組まれてる」means too?

Comment: I would consider that phrase to be 「君と二人で」, not just 「君と二人」 - 'together with you (君と) as a pair (二人で)'.